# [__NSDate objCType]: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios4

Sometimes I got error saying that unrecognized selector `objcType` was sent to an `NSDate` object:

> 2011-06-11 14:44:51.589 MyApp[354:307] -[__NSDate objCType]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b0d5a0
>
> 2011-06-11 14:44:51.732 MyApp[354:307] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate
>   objCType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b0d5a0'

What I do is loading data from sqLite using Core Data by calling `[[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]`. I use a predicate, which ensures that the only (NSManaged)objects having their attribute `kickoffTime` of type `NSDate` in a specified range are fetched:

```
NSDate * fromDate = ...
NSDate * toDate = ...
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"( ( %@ <= kickoffTime +0 ) && ( kickoffTime +0 <= %@ ) )", fromDate, toDate];

// Add the predicate to the fetchRequest
[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchRequest] setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;

if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) 
{
    ...
}
```

I do not really know what the problem might be. I probably misuse the core data predicate in some way, forcing the framework to send the `objCType` message to NSDate object in order to find out type of the object. Does anybody have some suggestions?

Here is a few things I have observed:

- the NSDate object to which is sent the problematic selector is the kickoffTime attribute of my NSManagedObject
- it happens pretty randomly so it is not easy to reproduce
- the NSDate object to which the unrecognized selector is sent appears to be valid object (I could print it out in gdb)

Here is the top of the stack:

> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x3587a987
>   __exceptionPreprocess + 114
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x34a8249d
>   objc_exception_throw + 24
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x3587c133
>   -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
>
> 3   CoreFoundation                      0x35823aa9 ***forwarding*** +
>   508
>
> 4   CoreFoundation                      0x35823860
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
>
> 5   Foundation                          0x3121ac69
>   +[_NSPredicateUtilities add:to:] + 40
>
> 6   Foundation                          0x31221225
>   -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 688
>
> 7   Foundation                          0x3117e045
>   -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] +
>   176
>
> 8   Foundation                          0x312255fb
>   -[NSCompoundPredicateOperator
>   evaluatePredicates:withObject:substitutionVariables:] + 186
>
> 9   Foundation                          0x3121e43f
>   -[NSCompoundPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 186
>
> 10  Foundation                          0x3117df8d -[NSPredicate
>   evaluateWithObject:] + 16
>
> 11  CoreData                            0x356e8edf
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 2014
>
> 12  CoreData                            0x357a041b
>   -[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:] + 766
>
> 13  MyApp                             0x000195ef
>   -[MatchesCalendarDataSource loadMatchesFrom:to:delegate:] + 138

Comment: What's "+0" in "kickofftime +0"? What happens if you drop it?

Comment: @Yuyi, exactly what I thought: drop the +0.

Comment: Are you using the FetchedResultsController in another thread or a situation where another thread might be spawned to do the work. If your MOC belongs to another thread this will happen.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! It did work with +0, but I will try to remove it as it served for some backward compatibility issue.

Comment: @Waren Thanks for pointing that out. The MOC should be accessed only on the main thread, but I will double check that. Did you have seen this kind of problem before? And if you did, was the cause bad using of MOC in multithreaded environment?

Comment: altough this question has already been answered, I also run into this kind of problem. When things happen randomly and with bizarre error messages, it is usually a memory management problem of some kind of deallocated object, for example how you calculate fromDate,toDate ? I solved by doing three things: running analyzer, running profiler with zombie enabled, and rewrite my methods for accepting [entity objectID] in place of entity itself, which could cause problem in a multithreaded environment as Apple docs say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `objcType` is a selector/method of NSValue and its subclasses like NSNumber. That means that the NSDate object is being treated like a NSValue at some point. It most likely happens when the NSDate is being wedged into a mathematical operation which it doesn't support.

In a predicate, a NSDate will often be converted to a NSTimeInterval which is a double. If you log the predicate you have above, the date will resolve something like this:

```
CAST(335110182.022141, "NSDate") <= kickoffTime + 0 AND kickoffTime + 0 <= CAST(335110182.022141, "NSDate")
```

... which is the NSDate being cast to a double. That is where your problem comes from. I suspect it arises because the predicate parser cannot always resolve the precedence.

You can probably resolve the problem just by:

```
(CAST(335110182.022141, "NSDate") <= kickoffTime + 0) AND (kickoffTime + 0 <= CAST(335110182.022141, "NSDate"))
```

However, the `+0` does absolutely nothing in a predicate besides cause problems so I would just lose it.

BTW when you say:

> What I do is loading data from sqLite using Core Data by calling

... that suggest that you are thinking of Core Data as an object wrapper for sqlite. It isn't and thinking that way will get you into trouble *especially* with predicates.

Comment: Thanks for clarification on what's going on in there. Not sure if the removal of +0 will help. I just wonder how come that parser sometimes (in vast majority of cases as it was not reproducible easily) do the parsing ok and just sometimes it have problems.

Comment: The cast probably fails depending on the actual value of the NSTimeInterval of the NSData object e.g. if it happened to be something like 192837465.0 it might end up parsed as a integer instead of a double. Could you somewhere be accidentally assigning a NSNumber to the data variable or vice versa?

Comment: I'm not sure if the `+0` causes the problem or not but it needs to go because it serves no function in the predicate. It's just clutter.